# Обрезать путь к диску до - storage/emulated/0/

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как обрезать путь к диску?

В onCreate

```
Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesImage = getAbsoluteDir(this, null);
```

метод обрезки пути:

```
public static File getAbsoluteDir(Context ctx, String optionalPath) {
    String rootPath;
    if (optionalPath != null && !optionalPath.equals("")) {
        rootPath = ctx.getExternalFilesDir(optionalPath).getAbsolutePath();
    } else {
        rootPath = ctx.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
    }
    // extraPortion is extra part of file path
    String extraPortion = "Android/data/" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
            + File.separator + "files" + File.separator;
    // Remove extraPortion
    rootPath = rootPath.replace(extraPortion, "");
    return new File(rootPath);
}
```

Надо обрезать "Android/data/" и все остальное, но на выходе все равно полный путь получается. Надо чтобы осталось только storage/emulated/0/ .

И такой вопрос, этот костыль будет работать в дальнейшем, или гугл разработчики легко его прикроют, чтобы на внешний диск программисты не захламляли?

Comment: а в чем смысл обрезки? `getExternalFilesDir` уже не везде работает и его выпилят скоро совсем я думаю :(

Comment: Разве? Я так понял что выпиливают getExternalStorageDirectory(), а об getExternalFilesDir() я не слышал, он и не устаревший, и в статьях его советуют использовать, вместе с getExternalCacheDir() и getExternalMediaDir().. Или Вам что-то известно? Я вообще надеюсь на благоразумие, и то что оставят возможность..

Comment: упс... немного не то прочитал вначале)) я просто занимался тем же что и вы некоторое время назад, и решил что через встроенный механизм будет проще получать путь, зачем вы путь хотите обрезать, это спорный костыль который может не всегда правильно работать

Comment: А его разве еще не прикрыли?

Comment: Похоже Вы правы, в эмуляторе на 10 андроиде, без android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" - по обрезанному пути storage/emulated/0/ не записывается, видимо как-то они предусмотрели такой лёгкий вариант костыля..

Comment: @user7860670, с android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" в манифесте пока работает..